# How do I trouble shoot push notifications error "no valid 'aps-environment"

Tags: xcode, push-notification, certificate

I'm trying to retrieve my device token from my iPhone and send that token to a server for use in push notifications. I've logged into the developer porthole, added an application, and downloaded the certificate. I added this code to my application didFinishLaunching

```
NSLog(@"Registering for remote notifications"); 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

I also added

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
{
    NSLog(@"deviceToken: %@", deviceToken); 
} 

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", error); 
}
```

I'm getting this error

```
Error in registration. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application"
```

One thing I noticed is that in the developer porthole, it appended a number on the begining of the bundle ID under "description" I think the problem may have something to do with that. How can I make sure that the app details in the porthole are the same as in my target. Also, am I missing a step? do I have to do anything further with the certificate and xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the

```
<key>aps-environment</key>
```

string when opening the mobileprovision you are signing with in the text editor? If you don't, try re-issuing the mobileprovision in the developer.apple.com admin panel